# GWTP Hiding the parameters from the URL

Tags: gwt-mvp, gwtp

Is it possible to hide the parameters from the URL?

```
placeManager.revealPlace(new PlaceRequest("show").with("t", "e").with("x", "1"), true);
```

URL:

```
gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1%3A9997#show;t=e;x=1
```

I want the URL to be gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1%3A9997#show. Is this possible? or any other approach to do this?

I tried passing an event.. But the URL doesnt change in that case.

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in GWTP to hide parameters of Place(Request)s because a Place represents a state in the browser History and has to be (de)serializable into/from URL's.

I can't give you a good recommendation for a workaround because I don't know your architecture. If you like is dirty just use static fields which you initialize before revealing the place.